# Confusion between Sidenav and Vertical Nav

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm a little bit confused between [Sidenav](https://clarity.design/documentation/sidenav) and [Vertical Nav](https://clarity.design/documentation/vertical-nav)

Why `Sidenav` is different from `Vertical Nav`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical Nav is more fully featured and was introduced as a second option for navigation to avoid breaking existing implementations. At this point Sidenav is not deprecated, but generally Vertical Nav is the stronger choice.